# Задачка на питоне

Tags: python, классы, методы

Нужно в классе Solution создать метод который который принимает в качестве аргумента строку состоящую только из цифр, программа при этом должна вычитать сумму присутствующих в ней цифр (например "1234" = 10) Написал код, но что то не то, не могу подключить input хотя сама программа работает без ошибок но ничего не выводит, питоном не занимался до этого[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = input()
        self.num2 = 0

    def count(self):
        self.reminder = self.num1 % 10
        self.num2 = self.num2 + self.reminder
        self.num1 = self.num1 //10
        print(self.rereminder)
```

Comment: Для человека незнакомого с Питоном не плохо. Вы объявили класс, но не создали экземпляр и не вызвали его метод. Когда это сделаете, полезут ошибки с типами и опечатки. Алгоритм нуждается в доработке.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def count(self):
        s = input('Ведите строку из цифр: ')
        print(int(s) - sum(int(x) for x in s))

Solution().count()
```

```
Ведите строку из цифр: 1234
1224
```